# Blocked by Group Policy: trying to install TCP/IPv4 (Windows 10)

Tags: networking, windows-10, group-policy, ipv4

So I uninstalled Winsock and Winsock2 registry keys and now cannot connect to the internet. I am using the following [walkthrough](http://help.usfamily.net/vfaq.jsp?faq=198#remove) to try and reinstall Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) but every time I try and add the protocol I get a message saying I am blocked by Group Policy.

- I am a local administrator on the computer and I even added myself to the Network Configuration Operators group, but it's still displaying the message.
- I also tried enabling the administrator account and trying through there, but I still get the same message.

Any help getting past this is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You being a local administrator does not give you permissions to modify a group policy if your connecting to a domain.  It sounds like you are connecting to a domain.  Have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance?  You did export, the keys, before you deleted them right?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. Not sure why this got downvoted? SU doesn't seem to like beginners.

Comment: I voted on your question because I don't feel you have did enough background research.

Comment: Did you ever figure out which group policy was preventing this? For the record, the message that OP refers to shows up on non-domain machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I was able to resolve the issue using this utility, which added back the missing Winsock keys:
http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/winsockreset.html

> A Winsock reset utility with a few unique features. In addition to the usual fixes, it can scan for missing DLL files or reg entries and report; also allows you to import either the DEFAULT Winsock registry keys for that OS, or you may choose to import backups of your own Winsock registry keys from other Control Sets in the Registry (e.g. HKLM\System\ControlSet00x\Services\Winsock2, etc.) Fully portable

Answer (score -1):

**One more way to install Winsock and Winsock2:**
On the Windows taskbar, Right click on the internet icon and right click and troubleshoot problems.
This installed the required Winsock and Winsock2 registry keys for me.